# image file size larger when saving image to disk from database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, image, sql-server-2008

I'm inserting an image to a table with the `image` data type. The image i'm currently trying is a TIFF file. The file i'm inserting is 1.65MB. But when I retrieve the image again and save it to disk it's 2.48MB. What's the cause of this?

Here's my code inserting the image to the table.

```
 Dim _fileInfo As New IO.FileInfo(imagepath)
 Dim _NumBytes As Long = _fileInfo.Length
 Dim _FStream As New IO.FileStream(imagepath, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
 Dim _BinaryReader As New IO.BinaryReader(_FStream)
 pic= _BinaryReader.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(_NumBytes))
 _fileInfo = Nothing
 _NumBytes = 0
 _FStream.Close()
 _FStream.Dispose()
 _BinaryReader.Close()
 sqlcmd = New SqlCommand("Insert into table (pic) Values (@image)", sqlcon)
 sqlcmd.Parameters.Clear()
 sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", pic)
 sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
 sqlcon.close()
```

And here's the code for saving the image to disk

```
 If sqlcon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then sqlcon.Close()
 sqlcon.Open()
 sqlcmd = New SqlCommand("Select pic from table, sqlcon)
 sqldr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader
 sqldr.Read()
 Dim ImgStream As New IO.MemoryStream(CType(sqldr("pic"), Byte()))
 savingimage = Image.FromStream(ImgStream)
 SaveFileDialog1.Title = "Save File"
 SaveFileDialog1.FileName = "ImageFromDB"
 SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "JPEG (*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.jpe;*.jfif)|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.jpe;*.jfif|PNG (*.png)|*.png|TIF (*.tif;*.tiff)|*.tif;*.tiff"
 If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
      savingimage.Save(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff)
 End if
```

Comment: Does the bigger file still properly open in an image viewer application?

Comment: @Thilo Yes, I don't even see any difference.

Comment: It may have something to do with the quality level used to save the image, but I don't know if that applies to TIFF images.  see: [this example for jpeg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytz20d80(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3)

Comment: @crimson589, can you check is the length/size of ImgStream and savingimage  variable?

Comment: @FLICKER ImgStream length is 1737040, not sure about the savingimage variable which is an image, I don't see any property I can compare length with.

Comment: the number is almost 1.68 mb (size of original image) so as @TnTinMn, mentioned, it changes when you load the stream into image (my guess).

Comment: On doing [some research](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533846%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it appears that the TIFF format supports compression.  My guess is that the difference you are observing is due to efficiency difference between the encoder used to create the original image and that implemented by GDI.  By luck, I [found  a sample named MARBIBM.TIF](http://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/sample/c44cf1326c2240d38e9fca073bd7a805/download) that when loaded and then saved is actually slightly smaller than the original.